# Where I can I see the conole.log() output of chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that will give me the body size of http requests and responses, where I can then write them to a database for later use.

On the [API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_network/#examples) an example is given:

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  function(request) {
    if (request.response.bodySize > 40*1024) {
      chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
          'console.log("Large image: " + unescape("' +
          escape(request.request.url) + '"))');
    }
  }
);
```

This seems like almost exactly what I want but I cannot find the panel or console it wants to write to, no matter where I look.  I

I have the listener function in my `devtools.js` file, while `devtools.html` looks like:

`<script src="devtools.js"></script>`

If I modify the function and attempt to do a raw `console.log()` rather than wrapping it in `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval()` then the extension no longer compiles.

There seems to be spotty/limited documentation on the chrome extension APIs (or maybe it is just over my head), so any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be making a devtools panel, in which case right-click inside the panel and click "inspect", which will open another devtools for this context where you can see the console.

Comment: Circling back to say thanks, @wOxxOm.  The discovery that I needed to inspect the panel itself was a help.  Insert a poorly thought-out "Inspect-ception" joke here.